Power BI Refresh Problem due to its large size
The dashboard is connected to the live data, so it keeps on updating continuously, now due its size the refresh takes a lot of time and sometimes it crashes away. Now since the dashboard are presented on many screens for the visitors and inspectors. We cannot stop presenting it or reduce the data as it shows our live position in terms of many things. The file size has exceeded 400mb. Is there any way by which we ca nreduce the file size to 100mb or less?
I havent try much on it, since I cannot delete any column as every coulm is been used. I have searched on web a lot and try doing few things which were possible but din't came up with some good results.

I take it you are importing data, you need a database and direct query and a power bi premium per user to refresh more than 8 time a day
